# Is Ubuntu installed correctly?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, ssd

I installed Ubuntu a week ago.

I attempted to do a dual boot using my SSD drive (Disk 0) and leave my windows installation untouched (Disk 1).

The installation method I used involved dividing the partitions from the 'something else' menu, so I used that to create the space on my SSD.

The installation appeared to work, and for a while, I was booting straight into Ubuntu. I also couldn't access the boot menu after cycling through <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F12</kbd> etc., etc.

When investigating my partition on Gparted my results were:

```
dev/sda/(unallocated)

dev/sdb/(unallocated)

and then

dev/sdc1/nfts

dev/sdc2/linux-swap

dev/sdc3/ext4/
```

From this information, it seemed as though I had successfully installed Ubuntu but an error had caused me to wipe windows due to the unallocated space. I accepted this, whatever.

**Yesterday I started my computer and loaded into Windows....**

I have no explanation for why this happened.

Now when I trigger the boot menu using shift restart only windows appeared from the options. When looking at my disk management here is what I see:

[image]

It seems as if the SSD (Disk 0) isn't unallocated/empty.

Does this mean that Ubuntu is on there? Is there just something wrong with my boot methods.

I'm extremely confused and not really sure how to move forward.

Comment: Windows disk management doesn’t give much information about partitions formatted for Linux. You can clearly see your healthy Ubuntu partitions. Which disk are you booting? You could have healthy installs but cannot boot Windows from the Linux disk. What mode did you use for your Ubuntu install? Your Windows install will be  UEFI your Ubuntu install may be legacy which will not dual boot from grub

Comment: So my Linux is installed on Disk 0 and my Windows installed on Disk 1. I'm not sure how to alternate between the two to access my Ubuntu.

I'm not too sure what you mean by mode in installing Ubuntu but I put the install onto a memory and stick and went from there, making my partitions manually.

If my windows install is UEFI and Ubuntu install is Legacy as you suggest how do i resolve this problem and access both my operating systems?

Comment: Normally grub will allow you to boot Windows or Ubuntu. If that’s been installed to disk 0 and you are booting disk 1 then Windows is all you can get to. Try looking at your boot settings in the bios/UEFI and try to boot disk 0. Check the manual to find out how to do this if you don’t know